# What type to use for a date (without time) with Protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I need to define a field with a date (without time) in Protobuf.

I have found the page: [Protocol Buffers Well-Known Types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/), that page has the [Timestamp](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#timestamp), but at that page, there is not the suitable type for a date without time.

Comment: Dates are times. I think you mean that you wish to ignore the time modulo "day". Also, you will need to retain timezones because 2023-06-22 21:00:00 for me (US Pacific) is 2023-06-23 06:00:00 for someone in Frankfurt. You could use the Timestamp WKT and, when you convert from your preferred langauge's Date types, use midnight (e.g. "2023-06-23T00:00:00-00:00".

Comment: @DazWilkin I think this is not the best approach. Because there are various scenarios in which the time is not needed, for example the representation of the date of birth in some document. For example, in Java there are several types for dates and times: LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Background**

The Google Protocol Buffers Timestamp type is a typically rubbish thing, ignoring leap seconds. It is at least defined as being in UTC, but I note that no code is provided to guarantee that that is how one is initialised; a programmer could quite happily put in a local time rather than a UTC time, and no one's to know. Timestamp used for date is also problematic, because if one does the calculation as per Google's specification, you get the wrong answer for dates preceding the last leap second. This can be significant because if you have records with dates dating from back before the last leap second, they may have one date (say, 31/12/2016, at 23:59:60, which Google would record as 23:59:59), where as the number of seconds since calculated Google's way (i.e. there are no leap seconds) would put the date at 1/1/2017 - a whole day out in your parlance.

This is one of the problems with having TimeStamps for records that are "seconds since an epoch" - because people have different definitions of how many seconds there have been. Recorded as separate DMYhms fields, the record says what it meant at the time it was recorded. Recorded as a seconds-based timestamp, there is ambiguity.

For quite a lot of computer systems (especially in Google) that leap second was actually recorded as 31/12/2016 23:59:59 as slow their time references down to accommodate the extra second between the announcement of the leap second, and the leap second happening. This "doing it wrong" means that when someone wants to know the true date of a time they've calculated from some point in the future, the edge cases start getting worse and worse. If you're going back to 1972, there's been 28 leap seconds, meaning if you're interested in calculating the date of 30/06/1972 23:59:40, Google's way would have that as 01/07/1972 00:00:08.

Basically, almost all computing systems have been doing "time" badly since the very beginning. A good thing to have done would have to adopted International Atomic Time as a computer's time base, and left conversion (which is really not very difficult) to when "time" needed to be displayed, not recorded.

**Possible Answer**

Julian Day Number - or more likely Modified Julian Day Number could be your answer. This is an integer, starting at noon on Monday, January 1, 4713 BC, or for the Modified one 0:00 November 17, 1858 (or JD − 2400000.5). It's timezone-less, but most by convention would assume UTC. MDJ is at least anchored to midnight, which would simplify things!

It doesn't help with historic leapseconds as such, but it is an agreed "This is date, not date + time-set-to-zero".

JD / MJD can represent time as well, as a floating point number. But if you define it in a schema as an integer, then it can be nothing but date and is a well-define date epoch.

**More**

The astronomers, as you would expect, do have software to do "time" properly. Take a look at this: [PDF](http://www.iausofa.org/2021_0512_C/sofa/sofa_ts_c.pdf) and [pages](http://www.iausofa.org/2021_0512_C/). I've used this library, and wrapped it up with extra code to dynamically fetch leap second and other data from the International Earth Rotation Service, and can very accurately record and process timestamps accounting for leap seconds, etc. When you start rummaging around inside this, you see how easy it would have been for computers to adopt TAI as their timebase (and not a pseudo UTC). Google's "smearing" of time was a bad idea, for anyone interested in accuracy. In someways, Microsoft's dumb "do nothing" approach is better, because it's only timestamps around about the leap second that are wrong (at least, if recorded as separate DMYhms fields), not months worth in advance of it.

Leap seconds are presently a thing of the past; for now, there will be no more. This is because the earth's spin is speeding up. The longest solar day we've ever had was around about the 4th June 2020; Days now is about 1/4 second shorter.

There was due to be a negative leap second, but a lot of tech companies (who have blissfully been doing time wrong for decades) campaigned against it. Presently, our "legal" midnights (UTC midnight) is slipping further past solar midnight. We won't notice in our lifetime, but we have created a monster of a problem for generations to come! The sooner computers and all technology get off UTC and on to TAI, the better.